# How call components in Yii 1.1

Tags: php, yii

I have some component I want to make it separate currently my components looks like

```
-protected/components
    -GeneralFunction.php
    -CustomFunction.php
```

and my config I have called:

```
'components' => array(
   'general' => array('class' => 'GeneralFunction'),
   'custom' => array('class' => 'CustomFunction'),
),
```

Above code is working fine But I want to separate frontend and backend of my components like:

```
-protected/components
    -frontend
        -GeneralFunction.php
        -CustomFunction.php
    -backend
        -GeneralFunction.php
        -CustomFunction.php
```

and my config I am calling:

```
'components' => array(
   'general2' => array('class' => 'frontend.GeneralFunction'),
),
```

TestController.php

```
function actionTestComponent(){
    echo Yii::app()->general2->test(); exit;
}
```

I am getting this error message:

```
2017/12/19 11:17:54 [error] [exception.CException] CException: Alias "frontend.GeneralFunction" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing directory or file. in C:\xampp\htdocs\yii\framework\YiiBase.php:348
```

Please help me..

Answer (score 1):

After lots of research I found this:

```
'general2' => array('class' => 'application.components.frontend.GeneralFunction'),
```